# import command Linux

Tags: linux, import, command

My problem is that the "import" command Linux from the Terminal application for Mac cannot be found in application Terminal. I searched on Google for a way to install or impure it but in vain. How can I use the "import" command on Terminal for Mac in linux? In other words, the "Import" command could not be found under linux on the Mac.

Comment: is this thing you're looking for? [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-command-in-linux-with-examples/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.